# How many JWT tokens may be securely generated with one secret?

Tags: signature, jwt

I can remember from my crypto classes, that there is a limit on how many blocks can be securely encrypted with the same key. Before we reach the limit, we should rotate the key. Does it also hold true to JWT tokens? Is there a limit of token count, after which we should rotate the secret? If yes, what might be the limit for common signing algorithms like:

- HMAC + SHA256
- RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 + SHA256
- ECDSA + P-256 + SHA256